# How do I get my h2 element to appear under my header element?

Tags: html, css

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
<header id="header"> 
  Hoppity Edits
    <div class="logo">
      <img
```

```css
header {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive,  sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space around;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo > img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 405px;
}

 header > nav {
   font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

 ul {
  width: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#email-insert {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
<header id="header"> 
  Hoppity Edits
    <div class="logo">
      <img 
      id="header-img"
                    src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/1a/cf/ac1acffaa7f87b31c94cfab729167efb.jpg"
      alt="hoppity-logo"/>
    </div>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#photo-shop>
        Photo Shop</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#scrapbookex>
        Scrapbooks</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#pricing>
        Pricing</a>
  </nav>
    </header>
  
 <section id="email-insert">
   <h2> A family company founded on family principles
    </h2>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="email"
     placeholder= "Enter email to get started"
     required>
    </input>
   </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

```
      id="header-img"
                    src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/1a/cf/ac1acffaa7f87b31c94cfab729167efb.jpg"
      alt="hoppity-logo"/>
    </div>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#photo-shop>
        Photo Shop</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#scrapbookex>
        Scrapbooks</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#pricing>
        Pricing</a>
  </nav>
    </header>
  
 <section id="email-insert">
   <h2> A family company founded on family principles
    </h2>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="email"
     placeholder= "Enter email to get started"
     required>
    </input>
   </form>
  </section>
</div>






//CSS
header {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive,  sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space around;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo > img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 405px;
}

 header > nav {
   font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

 ul {
  width: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#email-insert {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: please, can you edit your question adding some description of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` instead of `absolute` to your header Like the snippet.
I just did whatever your wanted, But your code structure is real bad and you need to fix it. You are using `position` everywhere in your `css` code.

```css
header {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive,  sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space around;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo > img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 405px;
}

 header > nav {
   font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

 ul {
  width: 25vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#email-insert {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
<header id="header"> 
  Hoppity Edits
    <div class="logo">
      <img 
      id="header-img"
                    src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ac/1a/cf/ac1acffaa7f87b31c94cfab729167efb.jpg"
      alt="hoppity-logo"/>
    </div>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#photo-shop>
        Photo Shop</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#scrapbookex>
        Scrapbooks</a>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href=#pricing>
        Pricing</a>
  </nav>
    </header>
  
 <section id="email-insert">
   <h2> A family company founded on family principles
    </h2>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="email"
     placeholder= "Enter email to get started"
     required>
    </input>
   </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not the greatest code lol. I'm still very new to HTML/CSS, so I appreciate the feedback!